# SQL/Oracle return only field with identical value in 2nd column

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to return column 1 only if identical values are found in 2nd column of a repeating log. If any other value is seen exclude from result.

```
A   2
A   2
A   2
A   2
A   2
```

Exlude

```
B   2
B   1
B   2
B   3
B   2


 select b. column1 
    from 
    ( select * 
      from table 
      where column2 != 1

    ) b
  where b.column2 = 2
```

Results:

```
A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use aggregation and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT col1
FROM tab
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) = 1;
```

or if you need original rows:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(DISTINCT col2) OVER(PARTITION BY col1) AS cnt
      FROM tab t) s
WHERE s.cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the original rows, I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 <> t.col2);
```

If you just want the `col1` values (which makes sense to me), then I would phrase the aggregation as:

```
select col1
from t
group by col1
having min(col2) = max(col2);
```

If you want to include "all-null" as a valid option, then:

```
having min(col2) = max(col2) or min(col2) is null
```

Comment: I like MIN = MAX over COUNT(DISTINCT...). Regarding NULL, it is not clear what the requirement is. Perhaps if one value is NULL then all the values must be NULL also? If that is the requirement, then the MIN = MAX approach will not work (and neither will COUNT(DISTINCT...), since NULLs are ignored in these aggregate functions. Regardless, the OP should first state if the column is nullable, and if it is, what is the requirement when NULL is present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select column1 from (select column1,column2 from Test group by column1,column2) a group by column1 having count(column1)=1;
```

Comment: `count` is not `count(distinct...)` so your suggestion won't work.

Comment: @mathguy  first group by having both columns. So don’t need to get the distinct count. This solution works. I have checked.

Comment: Oh - I didn't even noticed you were including COLUMN2 in the GROUP BY. That is an even bigger mistake. It will select B from the OP's data, because `B, 1` appears just once in all the rows. So the count will be 1. This solution will not work - you have checked but you somehow got it wrong anyway.

Comment: @mathguy You wrong again B appears 3 times for 1,2,3 because group by having both columns. I have tested output